# Need to track the location using GPS in android

Tags: android

I am very new to android, i know how to get the location using `GPS`, but my doubt is,

Can I track each and every move of user in particular time?

Take an example : I have moved 20 km by car.How can I know the latitude and longitude of all the areas I have crossed ? Please suggest a related post or give me an idea to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an Android GPS tracking application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096192/create-an-android-gps-tracking-application)

Comment: Am i need to run the gps in background to track the location?

Comment: Android [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) Simply gice you a method to request a location update at every specified distance. So just part your GPS request in distance and track location simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the Android mobile application open-gpstracker is available at:

https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/checkout

You can checkout the code using SVN client application or via Git:

svn checkout

http://open-gpstracker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ open-gpstracker-read-only

git clone https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/

Debugging the source code will surely help you.

Source: [Create an Android GPS tracking application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096192/create-an-android-gps-tracking-application)

Answer (score 2):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683681/getting-location-data-on-an-android-device-in-certain-intervals) link & check answer of @CapDroid ,try the Code you can use TIMER for what you want

```
Timer t = new Timer(); t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, when, period);
```

**OR**

try This Code For Location Update @ certain Time Specified.

```
LocationManager mLocationManager =(LocationManager).getSystemService(mActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, new   GeoUpdateHandler());
```

Look at  [LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), just pass your time interval in parameter..
Hope this helps You.